# Groovy Mixin Usage Memory Leak

Tags: memory-leaks, groovy, mixins

I am working with Groovy 1.7.6 and we have a class which uses a basic mixin (simplified for this purpose below):

```
class MixinClass {
    def self
    def init(me){
        this.self = me
    }
}
```

I add this mixin to another class (Also simplified) as follows:

```
@Mixin(MixinClass)
class FunctionEntry  {

    def FunctionEntry(){
        init(this)
    }

..
```

The above is basically just passing a reference to the instance of the FunctionEntry class to the @mixin for reference (all though this could be any data)

If I now run a test, and loop through thousands of times calling `new FunctionEntry()`  I eventually get a Heap OOM error (note, the loop literally just instantiates the object, it doesn't store it anywhere ).

Having debugged the heap I see the problem is `MixinInMetaClass` - My conclusion is that even though I have discarded the object instance, the MixinInMetaClass is retaining the data and not being collected.

Has anyone come across this problem? Is this a known Groovy 1.7.6 problem?  I was under the impression that Mixins could hold state, but this evidence seems to suggest that the MixinInMetaClass is holing on to object data everytime i create an object.

Comment: Do you get the same with more recent versions of Groovy?

Comment: Not tested that scenario yet - will try to test that later on.

Comment: I've got it with Groovy 2.1.0, in a `1000000.times{}` loop. I received a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : GC overhead limit exceeded`, so I turned it off with `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`. Then I received only a non-GC OutOfMemory exception. It seems mixins are quite memory-consuming..

Comment: not sure you still read... is your loop only doing: 100_000.times{ new FundtionEntry() } ?

Comment: For what it's worth, I get slightly different behavior in Groovy 2.0.8 in a 64-bit environment.  Your test program quickly eats 4GB, but then stabilizes without running out of memory--it just thrashes GC forever.

Comment: I get a memory leak using Groovy `2.2.1` and Java `1.7.0_51`. I even tried using a `WeakReference` in the mixin. Normally, circular references should be cleaned up, so I don't have a solution, other than to say don't use circular references.